# Firestore disconnect

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, disconnect

After disconnecting the Internet, the listener "no internet" is triggered. After the connection is resumed, the "no internet" function also works. Success does not work, only after restarting the application. How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) regarding the use of transactions in Cloud Firestore:

> Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

With other words, you cannot use transactions when you are offline.

Also keep in mind that, when there is a loss of network connectivity (there is no network connection on user device), neither `onSuccess()` nor `onFailure()` methods are triggered. This behavior makes sense, since the task is only considered completed when the data has been committed (or rejected) by Firebase servers.

If you want to check whether you're receiving data from the server or the cache, use the `fromCache` property on the `SnapshotMetadata` in your snapshot event. If `fromCache` is `true`, the data came from the cache and might be incomplete. If `fromCache` is `false`, the data is complete and current with the latest updates on the server.

Comment: It is clear. But why does not the connection resume after the connection is lost?

Comment: You currently don't have any control over how the Firestore SDK manages its connections.

Most code that performs retries do so with an [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) algorithm.  This prevents the retries from happening so quickly that it impairs the performance of the host app, and also possibly consuming too much of the user's data plan.  However, this means that it may take some time to regain the connection.

Comment: Recovery takes place within 30-45 seconds. This is normal?

Comment: Yes. I experienced 10 seconds, even up to a minute.

Comment: You're welcome @ИльяЛитвинцев ! Cheers!